# Mock window.performance.getEntriesByType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, react-testing-library

In my component I check whether the page is reloaded and redirect to another page. I do it by following code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //this will prevent users from accidently refreshing / closing tab
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
      return "";
    };
   //check whether user reloaded
    if (
      window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "reload"
    ) {
      openExternalURL(process.env.GATSBY_MARKETING_URL);
    }
  }, []);
```

problem is I keep getting error in my Jest / react-test-library test cases as below

```
TypeError: window.performance.getEntriesByType is not a function
```

[image]

Even I tried to mock it like below but had no success.

```
window.performance = {
  getEntriesByType: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{ type: "reload" }]),
  measure: jest.fn()
};
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) object is **read-only** property, you can't assign a value to it. Instead, you can use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method to define read-only property.

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
      return '';
    };
    if (window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].type === 'reload') {
      console.log('open external url');
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>my component</div>;
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MyComponent } from './';

describe('67815262', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'performance', {
      value: {
        getEntriesByType: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{ type: 'reload' }]),
        measure: jest.fn(),
      },
    });

    render(<MyComponent />);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67815262/index.test.jsx (8.673 s)
  67815262
    ✓ should pass (38 ms)

  console.log
    open external url

      at examples/67815262/index.jsx:9:15

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.295 s
```

Comment: still having the same issue with this

Comment: @RyanBuckley You can ask a new question with minimal, reproducible example